# How to add Linux capability for CAP_IPC_OWNER in limits.conf?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-capabilities

I have a `/etc/security/limits.conf` file as follows

```
manu             -       memlock         unlimited
manu             -       rtprio          100
manu             -       nice            40
manu             -       stack           unlimited
```

Now I want the user "manu" to be able to use the `shmctl` function requiring `CAP_IPC_OWNER`, how should I modify this file to have this capability? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the place to set a capability. Use the system call `capset()` to do that, e.g. you start your process as root, set this capability with `capset()`, and then you can change your UID; or you can do that from another process but you need the pid.

An alternative is to use `setcap()` to set this as an attribute on your executable, see `setcap(8)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using limits.conf file allowed me to get capabilities for setting rt prio to my threads. How can we eplain that ?

Comment: Yes, `pam_limits` supports that, but in general capabilites are a different beast. There is some overlap, though.